# unselectable works in Firefox/Chrome/Safari, not working IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I need to be able to prevent from an image (placed in a DIV) of being selected.
I've tried many suggestion, but none seem to work on IE8.
The fact is, when the user selects the text with the mouse, in IE8 (and only IE8) the image gets selected as well.
It appeared the simpliest to upload an example to the web (rather than to here) so you can find the example in 
http://www.enosis-dev.com/select.html
click view source to see the code.
Any help will be appreciated.
Nir.

Comment: So why don't you accept an answer if it is the correct solution to your problem? Judging by the comments below it seems that you were happy with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<div>` with a background image instead of an `<img>`. If the image in question is 100px by 50px (for example), then something like this should do the trick:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 50px: background: url(/path/to/image.jpg);"></div>
```

If you need to support IE7 then you'll probably have to change `display: inline-block` to `display: block` using an IE7-specific stylesheet (preferably loaded using a conditional comment).

The problem with the above is that you need to know the image dimensions before replacing the `<img>` tags with `<div>` tags with backgrounds. You can do the replacement on the client side using jQuery to get around that problem but some care is needed to ensure that the images are loaded before they're replaced:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var $img         = $(this);
        var $replacement = $('<div/>');
        $replacement.css({
            width:      $img.width()  + 'px',
            height:     $img.height() + 'px',
            display:    'inline-block',
            background: 'url(' + $img.attr('src') + ')'
        });
        $img.after($replacement).remove();
    });
});
```

`$(window).load()` shouldn't fire until everything is loaded so all the image sizes should be known when it does.

If IE7 is an issue then you can put the `display: inline-block` bit in a class and override it using an IE7-specific stylesheet in the usual way.

Comment: I would have +1 if I could. This is was a step forward, indeed wasn't marked in IE8, unfortunately not something that I can make use of, because your method requires that one would knows in advance the measures of all images, which I don't.

Comment: @Nir O.: I added an update that does the img-to-div conversion on the client side. You tagged this with "jQuery" so maybe that'll work for you.

Comment: @Nir O.: Here's a quick example you can play with to see if this works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PkRED/

Comment: Hi there mu, is it a tested code or just a sketch?  I tested it ( http://www.enosis-dev.com/select.html ) and it does not work.

Comment: Your `select.html` has `<div style="display:...` in the HTML, that should be the original `<img>` tag. Have a look at the jsfiddle.net link from my comment.

Comment: Or try this one (which runs the image replace at a different time): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PkRED/1/

Comment: Works amazingly. Very creative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

    ele.onselectstart = function (){ return false; }


    ele.unselectable = "on";

Or Try

    user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none;  -o-user-select: none;  -moz-user-select: none;